# How do you describe a project should be advanced?

Tags: verbs

When you believe that a project should be advanced, which way(s) do you use out of following? Please also advise more native friendly expressions if you have.

1. We will proceed with the project on schedule.
2. We will take forward the project on schedule.
3. We will push ahead the project on schedule.
4. We will advance the project on schedule.

Comment: I'd use *"push the project ahead"* and *"take the project forward"*; although the word order in your suggested sentences isn't actually wrong, it's not as common. And as the first answer below might suggest, I think *"proceed with"* is probably the best choice here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of 'on' as a preposition here is incorrect. I would write:

> We will proceed with the project as scheduled.

That said, this does change, very slightly, the meaning of the sentence. 'on schedule' as a phrase of schedule is quite specific and the sentence above dilutes it somewhat. Consider:

> We will proceed with the project according to schedule.

I think this restores some specificity to the statement and is less passive.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/on-schedule